# Invalid File Name error when opening project stored in WSL2 file system in Android Studio

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

When trying to create an Android Studio project and setting its location to WSL2 file system, the error is shown:

```
Invalid File
```

[image]

Similarly when opening a project stored in WSL2 file system (example, here: \wsl$\Ubuntu\home\tyloubuntu\someproject), the error is also related to File name:

```
Gradle could not start your build.
> Cannot create service of type DefaultConfigurationCache using DefaultConfigurationCache constructor as there is a problem with parameter #10 of type ConfigurationCacheFingerprintController.
   > Cannot create service of type ConfigurationCacheFingerprintController using ConfigurationCacheFingerprintController constructor as there is a problem with parameter #5 of type FileCollectionFingerprinterRegistry.
      > Cannot create service of type FileCollectionFingerprinterRegistry using method VirtualFileSystemServices$BuildSessionServices.createFileCollectionFingerprinterRegistry() as there is a problem with parameter #1 of type List<FileCollectionFingerprinter>.
         > Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionServices.createFileHasher().
            > java.io.IOException: Incorrect function
```

or

```
The name of the file cannot be resolved by the system
```

[image]

One this is for certain, Android Studio (I am using Gradle build system) is having issues with WSL2.

**Tools info**:

Android Studio is installed on Windows 10.

Android Studio Version: Artic Fox Canary Beta 3

Windows 10 19042 build.

WSL2 for Ubuntu.

Gradle build system.

I tried following the same steps listed here, they worked fine with IntelliJ IDEA but giving file name errors for Android Studio: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/how-to-use-wsl-development-environment-in-product.html

My use case requires storing files in WSL2. Is there a workaround or a solution for this issue?